Proper way to get the AppSettings for all app services in my resource group using Azure SDK for .Net
I am attempting to get a specific resource group, looping through the app service plans, then the app services, and inspecting the SiteInfo.AppSettings property but that property is always null for me.
Is this the proper way to view/inspect the AppSettings on my app services with the Azure SDK?
An anonymized version of my code below:
var credentials = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions() { TenantId = tenantid });
ArmClient client = new ArmClient(credentials);
var groupid = ResourceGroupResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(mySubscriptionID, myResourceGroupID);
var group = client.GetResourceGroupResource(groupid);
        
foreach(var plan in group.GetAppServicePlans())
{
    foreach(var app in plan.GetWebApps())
    {
        // Check a specific setting like WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE with app.SiteConfig.AppSettings, but it's always null
    }
}



The SiteConfig.AppSettings being null can be a common issue if the app settings are not retrieved properly.

Code:
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.ResourceManager.AppService;
using Azure.ResourceManager.AppService.Models;

// Initialize credentials and client
var credentials = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions() { TenantId = tenantid });
ArmClient client = new ArmClient(credentials);

// Get the resource group
var groupid = ResourceGroupResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(mySubscriptionID, myResourceGroupID);
var group = client.GetResourceGroupResource(groupid);

// Iterate through app service plans and web apps
await foreach (var plan in group.GetAppServicePlans().GetAllAsync())
{
    await foreach (var app in plan.GetWebApps().GetAllAsync())
    {
        // Fetch the app settings for each web app
        var appSettings = await app.GetAppSettingsAsync();
        if (appSettings != null)
        {
            foreach (var setting in appSettings.Properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{setting.Key}: {setting.Value}");
            }
        }
    }
}


firstly, Initialize the ArmClient with the appropriate credentials and get the resource group using client.GetResourceGroupResource(groupid).

Iterate through the app service plan and web app using asynchronous GetAllAsync() methods then fetch the app settings for each web app using app.GetAppSettingsAsync().



Hi Suresh, when I call GetWebApps() I get objects of type WebSiteData which does not have a method GetAppSettingsAsync()  I'm using the latest version of Azure.ResourceManager (1.12.0) and Azure.Core (1.41.0)

Yeah! WebSiteData type indeed does not have the GetAppSettingsAsync method, but you can get the WebSiteResource from it to access the app settings.
